# Using JAVA to create Excel file: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name

Tags: java, vb.net, jsf

I have a serious problem in my web application. I am using POI api to write on excel through java code.

It is working fine while running with Java Main method (working only once). But when I try execute my application again I have the following exception:

```
Message: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name 
StackTrace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
The workbook already contains a sheet of this name
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:767)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:108)
```

Follow part of the my code below:

```
public class ReportGenerator {

   private Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    public void generateReport(Map<String, Node> nodes, 
String reportOption) throws Exception {     

     this.FILENAME = getFilePath(DIRECTORY_TEMPORARY_REPORT);
     export(FILENAME);
     new Chart(FILENAME, this.reportOption);
     wb.close();
   }

    //export data to excel file
    public void export(String pathname) throws IOException, ParseException {

     if(this.reportOption.equals("MGWSCC")){    
        exportMgwTop();
        exportMgwMethodology();
        exportRelease(); 
     }else if(this.reportOption.equals("MSCSCC")){
         exportMscTop();
         exportMscMethodology();
         exportRelease();   
     }else if (reportOption.equals("MSCVLR")){
            exportMscTop();
            exportVlrTop();
            exportMscMethodology();
            exportRelease();
        }   

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathname));
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    vlrPeaks.delete(0, vlrPeaks.length());
    topValues.delete(0, topValues.length());
    raw.delete(0, raw.length());
    vlrRawData.delete(0, vlrRawData.length());
}
```

Its working fine, but only once...when I try execute again this code I have the exception above.

thanks for your help

Comment: So you ran it once, and created a workbook with that name. Then upon running it another time, that name already exists, you either need to delete it and run again, or create unique names on every run.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running the code a second time, still using "createSheet()". If you run "createSheet()" on a woorkbook that already has a sheet of that name, it will fail with that exception.

Use something like the following instead:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
if(sheet == null)
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
```

Comment: Hello @carusocomputing, thanks for your comments, but I already make it. In other method I do this: **XSSFSheet top = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheet("SheetName"){
      top = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("SheeName");
     }**         I need know **How can I create an other workbook when I running the code a second time?** thanks